# What does a lock icon with non-usable password entry field instead of login screen mean on a mac?

Tags: macos, screen-lock

I powered on my MacBook Pro 2019 (I think with Catalina) after about a month of non-use and after a long wait it came up .. *sort of*

(note: the picture should be 'level' but well I guess I could use some practice with taking a steady/even picture..)

[image: Photo of a padlock on a Mac screen instead of the Login screen]

The password field can not be interacted with and no keypresses are accepted.  I can click on the right arrow but nothing happens.

The Mac *is* visible to **Find my**, but it does not play a sound when requested.

[image: Screenshot of the list of devices in the Find My app listing the Mac with the padlock]

The Mac *did* boot a few minutes earlier then after a couple of minutes decided to do that weird thing.  Rebooting did not help.  It *did* play a sound once, then refused to do it again.  I do wonder why it starts to play nicely but then goes into this mode.

So:

- what is going on
- how can I get my mac/Desktop back?
  Note that this Mac *is* findable via **Find my** and that it is neither locked nor erased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am totally hosed here!

Set up a "Genius" appointment at an Apple Store and they said "For a Firmware lock we can not help you unless you have an original receipt from Apple."

I had bought this off of Craigslist from a private seller last year.  I guess something got "off" and caused it to jump to firmware just recently.  But I don't have that password.

Apple's suggestion?  ***Recyle it***.  I'm not kidding.

I guess this can help them sell their "Apple refurbished" machines - which sell for only a fraction less than retail?

I have valuable data on that machine so it's not just the replacement cost.

The only recourse now would be to extract/replace the bios chip - following this video.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4kqC2MaQjg  I'm not in a position to do that in term of equipment or time.

Comment: Oh, really sorry to read that. So he undoubtedly confirmed it is a firmware password ? Maybe you can contact the previous owner... Else I also found that, that does not involves soldering, but still complicated. https://gist.github.com/willzhang05/e5b5563cdc65514dfb7ca131e03ca4b2

Comment: Also, according to the site below, firmware lock can be activated remotely, if the "Lost mode" is activated - did the previous usernot remove completely its account ?  https://mac-optimization.bestreviews.net/bypassing-efi-lock-on-your-mac/

Comment: I am unable to contact the seller. He is a nice guy - but probably just forgot about the firmware lock.  It's also possible he locked the account remotely when not remembering this whole thing.

In the end the motherboard and chassis are  _done_ .  But I still do hope to extract the hard disk to recover my data.

Comment: As to the "other" way - ie reprogramming the bios - it is absolutely no less complicated then re-soldering and arguably quite  bit _more_ so.  Both of those are flaming non-starters for a time-strapped person ..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a firmware password. But this should appear only at boot...
(more info : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455 )

Is your mac remotely managed by your company ?
Did you try booting with alt/option pressed ?

Comment: It's a personal mac.  I tried booting with shift also with various combination of [alt]-cmd-R.  will try with _just_ `alt` now..   But it seems to me there might be something hardware related e.g. hard disk. Tried _alt_: no dice .  i have not set any firmware password: and actually this screen got started sometime after having gotten into the O/S successfully. I think there's something wrong with O/S, disk or both.

Comment: Even if the interface looks really Apple-ish, I hope this is not like a data-locking malware. If you have precious data on it, you can try to boot with T, and see if the thunderbolt logo appears (that is target mode, to use your mac as an external drive for another mac).

Comment: Was FileVault activated ?

Comment: No, I did not use `FileVault`

Comment: "you can try to boot with T"  what is 'T' ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, with the 'T' key pressed.

Comment: OK well my macbook appears to be completely hosed: no suggestions can help presently.  Have an Apple Genius appointment in a couple hours: let's see what they say!

Comment: See my answer below.